# Vectorizing conditional count in Pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas, vectorization

I have a Pandas script that counts the number of readmissions to hospital within 30 days based on a few conditions. I wonder if it could be vectorized to improve performance. I've experimented with df.rolling().apply, but so far without luck.

Here's a table with contrived data to illustrate:

```
ID  VISIT_NO    ARRIVED      LEFT     HAD_A_MASSAGE   BROUGHT_A_FRIEND
1       1      29/02/1996  01/03/1996       0                 1
1       2      01/12/1996  04/12/1996       1                 0
2       1      20/09/1996  21/09/1996       1                 0
3       1      27/06/1996  28/06/1996       1                 0
3       2      04/07/1996  06/07/1996       0                 1
3       3      16/07/1996  18/07/1996       0                 1
4       1      21/02/1996  23/02/1996       0                 1
4       2      29/04/1996  30/04/1996       1                 0
4       3      02/05/1996  02/05/1996       0                 1
4       4      02/05/1996  03/05/1996       0                 1
5       1      03/10/1996  05/10/1996       1                 0
5       2      07/10/1996  08/10/1996       0                 1
5       3      10/10/1996  11/10/1996       0                 1
```

First, I create a dictionary with IDs:

```
ids = massage_df[massage_df['HAD_A_MASSAGE'] == 1]['ID']
id_dict = {id:0 for id in ids}
```

Everybody in this table has had a massage, but in my real dataset, not all people are so lucky.

Next, I run this bit of code:

```
for grp, df in massage_df.groupby(['ID']):

    date_from = df.loc[df[df['HAD_A_MASSAGE']==1].index, 'LEFT']
    date_to = date_from + DateOffset(days=30)

    mask = ((date_from.values[0] < df['ARRIVED']) &
        (df['ARRIVED'] <= date_to.values[0]) &
        (df['BROGHT_A_FRIEND'] == 1))

    if len(df[mask]) > 0:
        id_dict[df['ID'].iloc[0]] = len(df[mask])
```

Basically, I want to count the number of times when someone originally came in for a massage (single or with a friend) and then came back within 30 days with a friend. The expected results for this table would be a total of 6 readmissions for IDs 3, 4 and 5.